# PostgreSQL: SELECT INTO - how to create indexes?

Tags: postgresql

since SELECT INTO NEW_TABLE FROM QUERY creates NEW_TABLE the new table will not have any indices. Is there some way to utilise SELECT INTO with an existing table where I've created the desired indices? I am aware of INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT ... but I've encountered very bad performance compared to SELECT INTO.

Thanks

Comment: Posting a title all in caps won't get you answers any faster - rather the reverse.

Comment: that's probably true - sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what performance issues do you talk about, but generally, if you're making copy of table, it's **much** better to create indexes after inserting data.

I.e. - you do:

```
create table new_table as select * from old_table;
```

Then just create indexes.

One option to simplify index creation is to use pg_dump and it's -s and -t options, with some "grep":

```
pg_dump -s -t old_table database_name | \
    grep -E '^CREATE.*INDEX' | \
    sed 's/old_table/new_table/g'
```